# Failed to write the txt file in java

Tags: java

I am working on a function that enables the user to check a single student's assessment result. I use try and catch, but when I run the code, the system runs directly to the catch part, and the file's content is blank. I am not sure the reason about this problem. Here is my code:

```
System.out.println('\n' + "Please enter the Student's uni that you would like to call. Type 'exit' to leave");
       String studentInfo = s.nextLine();
       if (studentInfo.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
       userSelection = "exit";
                                        }

      boolean studentFound = false;
      for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {

      if (studentInfo.equalsIgnoreCase(students.get(i).getStudentUI())) {
      studentFound = true;

       try {
             File singleStudentList = new File(studentInfo + " .txt");
             PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(singleStudentList);

             System.out.println(studentUniLists.get(i));

             writer.println(studentUniLists.get(students.indexOf(studentInfo)));
             writer.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Problem writing the file. Please make sure the path is correct");
            }

           }
        }
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You are not printing out the exception's message!  e.printStackTrace().  Print it out, edit the question, and show the stack trace, please.

Comment: If you're code is getting straight to the catch the problem is probably on one of the constructor for File or PrintWriter. Have a look at the documentation to see the specific exceptions they throw: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.lang.String- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.io.File-
To my experience the problem is probably that the file you're trying to open doesn't exists

Comment: Use `System.out.println(singleStudentList.getCanonicalPath())` to display the file path it is trying to use. It's possible your program is not looking in the correct directory.

Comment: you should print the error by System.out.println(e.printStackTrace()); then you will see error message in your console. please try this and let us know the error message.

Comment: provide the full source code... what kind of object is students etc

Answer (score 1):

My hunch is that your error is in one of these two lines:

```
     System.out.println(studentUniLists.get(i));

     writer.println(studentUniLists.get(students.indexOf(studentInfo)));
```

You haven't included code as to what studentUniLists is, so there is some guesswork here.

My guess is that students.indexOf(studentInfo) could be returning -1, so then when you do studentUniLists.get(-1) on a `List`, this is going to give you an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. You should really only be catching the `IOException`, so that you can detect this kind of issue

Answer (score 0):

Probably index out of bounds somewhere, e.g:

```
System.out.println(studentUniLists.get(i));
```

Are you sure `studentUniLists` has the index i?
Since you wrote there is no output and it just goes directly to catch.

As commented elsewhere, printing the actual exception helps.

Answer (score 0):

You catch ANY Exception and you print to the console that this is file related problem. It does not have to be.
I suggest you add into your catch clause e.printStackTrace() to print the real problem. Secondly you should consider avoiding catching Exception as it is too broad. It might be worth catching exception that is related to file problems in the first place and leaving the rest uncaught.

Looking at the documentation - PrintWriter will be unlikely to throw errors. Comstructor may throw FileNotFoundException or SecurityException. CheckErrors is the function you need for checking file related errors.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#checkError(). Yet I believe you have non file related problem like NullPointerException or IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, With Jdk 1.7 when you open the file use the **try with ressources** to let the jvm do the close automaticly.

```
File singleStudentList;

try (singleStudentList = new File(studentInfo + " .txt")) {         

         PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(singleStudentList);

}
```

**Second,** The error is getting by this : **new File(studentInfo + " .txt")**
you're always creating the empty file **"true .txt"**

**Third,** print the error by **ex.printStackTrace();**